# Prolog predicate that prints items on odd positions. Help me to write code?

Tags: prolog

Prolog predicate that prints items on odd positions, for example ? `odd([2,4,7,3,2,8,])`. result is 2,7,2

Comment: Please show what you have tried, what the outcome is and what you expect. See [ask]

Answer (score -1):

A possible way

```
odd([]).
odd([_]).

odd([A, _ | Tail]) :-
  writeln(A),
  odd(Tail).
```